# Hibernate: Mapping a one to many relationship on a legacy table that uses columns as rows for the one to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I am working with a table on a database that I cannot change. The table has a list of user contacts for example email, facebook, twitter etc. Each of these contacts has a column. So the table looks something like this:

```
USER {
    user_id,
    email,
    facebook,
    twitter,
    ...
}
```

I need to link this database to an application that uses Spring / Hibernate. This application expects the relation to be One-to-Many to the user meaning:

```
User {
    user_id,
    ...
}
Contacts {
    contact_id,
    user_id,
    type,
    value
}
```

How can I achieve this conversion using hibernate mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't make `Contact` an entity, but make it a POJO, and return a list of those POJOs in the `getContacts` method of the User:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    List<Contact> result = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    if (this.facebook != null) {
        result.add(new Contact("facebook", this.getId(), this.facebook));
    }
    if (this.twitter != null) {
        result.add(new Contact("twitter", this.getId(), this.twitter));
    }
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Having an ID in the contact doesn't really makes sense, since Contact is not an entity.

Note that your question is a bit strange: normally, you design your Hibernate entities based on the underlying database schema. Why id the application designed like this if the underlying schema is as you described. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The application is such that it mines data from various databases. It has no knowledge of the database. We use hibernate to map the database in to POJOs the application understands.

We certainly have many ways to solve this problem through code changes. I am however looking to hibernate mapping to do this seamlessly.